# What is the interval for an exponential random variable?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose that I have generated a random number $x$ using an exponential distribution with rate parameter $\lambda$. How can I find an interval $[a,b]$ such that $x$ is in this interval with probability $p$.

I know the lower bound, $a$, is zero, but how can I find the upper bound?

Comment: Such an interval is not uniquely determined:  For any lower bound $L > 0$ such that $1 - F_X(L) \ge p$, there exists a $U$ such that $F_X(U) - F_X(L) = p$.

Comment: not sure if I understand what you are saying: As I read in wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) exponential distribution is equal to zero for negative real numbers, I think this means if I generate a random number using an exponential distribution this random number cannot be a negative number so the lower bound is zero.

Comment: What heropup was saying is that if $p\lt 1$, then there are infinitely many intervals $[a,b]$ such that $0\le a\le b$ and $\Pr(a\le X\le b)=p$. However, we can always, if we wish, choose $a=0$, and then $b$ is uniquely determined.

Comment: @AndréNicolas thanks, for exponential case, $a$ is always zero right?

Comment: My comment above said that if we are solving $\Pr(a\le X\le b)=p$ for $a$ and $b$, there are infinitely many possibilities for $a$ and $b$. The choice $a=0$ is one of them.

Comment: Hint: Use the cumulative distribution function.